# wait -n ; is not waiting for all subshells to complete

Tags: bash, shell

I have this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


DIRN=$(dirname "$0")

OUTPUT_PATH=${PROJECT_ROOT:-$PWD}/npm-install-output.log

(cd $(dirname "$0")/one && echo $PWD && rm -rf node_modules ; npm --loglevel=warn --progress=false install) &
(cd $(dirname "$0")/two && echo $PWD && rm -rf node_modules ; npm --loglevel=warn --progress=false install) &
(cd $(dirname "$0")/three && echo $PWD && rm -rf node_modules ; npm --loglevel=warn --progress=false install) &

wait -n; echo "EXIT CODE => $?"

EXIT=$?

echo " all done with parallel installs "
echo " => bash exit code for script '$(dirname "$0")/$(basename "$0")' => $EXIT" &&
exit ${EXIT}
```

from my logging output, seems very clear that one of the subshells runs after the `wait -n` call.

How can I use wait or another construct such that I wait for all subshells to complete?

Comment: Loose the `-n` after `wait`.  BTW, your `EXIT=$?` is suspect, it will get the exit code of the preceding `echo` statement.

Comment: @cdarke yes that's true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`help wait` is pretty clear about that:

> If the `-n` option is supplied, waits for the next job to terminate and
>       returns its exit status.

Use `wait` instead of `wait -n`

---

If you are interested in all three return values use:

```
for i in 1 2 3 ; do
    wait -n
    echo "exit code $?"
done
```

Comment: thanks, yeah I was thinking that, but the definition for wait -n does not make it clear that it only waits for the next job. It could in theory wait for all jobs.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me, and you can't argue with that :) Maybe I'm just stupid

Comment: In some more magical programming languages like bash, it would be possible for the  wait -n line to be invoked several times, for each finished subshell

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: The docs would be more clear if they said: "If the -n option is supplied, waits for the next job, *and only the next job*, to terminate and returns its exit status." In other words, it doesn't keep waiting for the next job, if there is more than 1.

Comment: I recommend to read also `man 3 wait` which explains `wait()` function in the POSIX libc. The bash builtin is based on that